# Converting a byte to a String in Android

Tags: java, android

Previously i was converting a `Bitmap` image to a `String` using the method below

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

But now i have a `File` in form of bytes in which i would like to get the `String` of this file

I have tried

```
public String getStringbytes(byte[] buffer) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    buffer.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);// this is the error
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

How do i convert the bytes passed to the method to a `String`? In other words how do i modify the part where i was compressing the `Bitmap` image before to capture the bytes to be converted to `String`?

Comment: What you do mean by "compressing a `byte[]` buffer with JPEG" in the second function?

Comment: this may help you [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-byte-array-to-string-in-java/)

Comment: There is no file in your code. Are you asking how to convert byte to String or bytearray to base64 encoded string? You have presented how to do it in your code, so what is your actual problem?

Comment: Why do you want to compress a jpeg again? Is it not already compressed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking BUT if what you're asking is this:

"I have one function that takes a Bitmap as input and returns a String by doing the following conversion steps: Bitmap --> byte[] --> base64 String,

but I also want a function that takes a Byte Array as input and returns a String with the following conversion steps: byte[] --> base64 String"

Then try this:

```
public String getStringbytes(byte[] buffer) {

String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT);
return encodedImage;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to convert the `byte[]` to Bitmap through [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int)) and pass the new Bitmap to the first method?

Comment: Only if the `byte[]` contains an image.

Comment: @Henry That's a precondition by the algorithm itself. If not, the codification to JPG would be nonsense.